# MySQL Error 1005 errno. 150 with Primary Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb

I'm adding a functionality to a database I have previously created. I have a table named "Test" which holds data about a series of questions. This data can include a number of dynamic fields added by the user, so I have a table named Test_Header_Values which will hold data about which header field is being fulfilled and the test it is part of.

So far so good, I have created both tables but have an Error 1215 when creating a Foreign Key. I had an error 1005 previously, but I tried on another database and it throws the 1215. I have checked infinite times the typing, the relationship, the indexes, and it should work, but I can't get it done.

Here you have the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `fk_id_checklist` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sent_date` date NOT NULL,
  `fk_id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_id_user_company` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`fk_id_checklist`,`sent_date`,`fk_id_user`,`fk_id_user_company`),

  KEY `fk_user_test_idx` (`fk_id_user`,`fk_id_user_company`),

  CONSTRAINT `fk_test_user` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id_user`, `fk_id_user_company`) 
    REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`, `fk_id_company`) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_test_checklist` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id_checklist`) 
    REFERENCES `checklist` (`id_checklist`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `test_header_values` (
  `fk_id_checklist` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_sent_date` date NOT NULL,
  `fk_id_field` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_id_user_company` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`fk_id_checklist`,`fk_id_field`,`fk_id_user`,`fk_id_user_company`,`fk_sent_date`),

  KEY `fk_field_idx` (`fk_id_field`),

  KEY `fk_values_test_idx` (`fk_id_checklist`,`fk_sent_date`,`fk_id_user`,`fk_id_user_company`),

  CONSTRAINT `fk_values_field` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id_field`) REFERENCES `fields` (`id_field`) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_values_test` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id_checklist` , `fk_id_user` , `fk_id_user_company` , `fk_sent_date`) 
    REFERENCES `test` (`fk_id_checklist` , `fk_id_user` , `fk_id_user_company` , `sent_date`) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

If I remove the constraint `fk_values_test` it works perfectly. With this line, it returns the aforementioned error.

I have followed [this guide](http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/) and all the questions I found on SO but I have been unable to find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the problem.

Seemingly, the index for the foreign key must have the same column order that the constraint, which is something that I didn't find specified.

Changing the constraint to `` `fk_id_checklist` , `fk_id_user` , `fk_id_user_company` , `fk_sent_date` `` solves this error.